Solve this cryptarithm: PI * R^2 = AREA
PI × R^2 = AREA
If each letter in this expression (but not the exponent 2) is replaced with a corresponding digit, the resulting equation will be valid.
What are the values of the letters if
Case 1: no two letters can have the same value?
Case 2: there's no restriction to the value an letter can take? This means that if P = 6 then there can be other letter(s) which are also equal to 6.
P.S: Source contains the solution so will post it later.

Seems easy with a direct search, but perhaps there is a more clever solution.  Note:  it's not clear from the rules whether $2$ is allowed as a value, though the solution found by search does not use an extra $2$.

@lulu , an alphabet can take the value of 2 in both the cases.

Didn't mean to do that.  I'll delete those comments.

For case 1, the solution is unique.

@Lucenaposition , no leading 0s.

Now that a solution is posted, what is the source please?

@BenjaminWang , pls click on show answer on this link. It mentions the source: https://www.futilitycloset.com/2024/07/17/cryptarithm-2/

Solution for case 1:

 Leading zeros in multi-digit integers are not permitted so $A\ne0$ so $AREA>999$. This means $PI\times R^2>999$. If $R\le3$ then $R^2\le9$ so $PI\times R^2\le99\times9<999$ which is too low. So $R\notin\{0,1,2,3\}$.


 Next, if $R=4$ then $AREA$ is a multiple of $16$ so $A$ is even.
 Leading zeros in multi-digit integers are not permitted so $A\ne0$. But that means $2000>99\times4^2\ge PI\times R^2=AREA$ so $A=1$. This is not possible so $R\notin\{4\}$.


 Next, if $R=5$ then $AREA$ is a multiple of $25$ so $A$ is $0$ or $5$.
 Leading zeros in multi-digit integers are not permitted so $A=5$. But that means $99\times5^2\ge PI\times R^2=AREA\ge5000$. This is not possible so $R\notin\{5\}$.


 Next, if $R=6$ then $AREA$ is a multiple of $36$ so $A$ is even.
 Leading zeros in multi-digit integers are not permitted so $A\ne0$. But that means $4000>99\times4^2\ge PI\times R^2=AREA$ so $A<4$. Therefore, $A=2$. So $AREA=26E2$. $26E2$ is a multiple of $9$ so $2+6+E+2$ is a multiple of $9$. This means $E=8$ but $2682$ is not a multiple of $36$. So $R\notin\{6\}$.


 Next, if $R=8$ then $AREA$ is a multiple of $64$. The only multiple of $64$ that is of the form $A8EA$ is $4864$ but then $PI=4864/64=76$ so $E=I$. So $R\notin\{8\}$.


 Next, if $R=9$ then $AREA$ is a multiple of $81$. The only multiple of $81$ that is of the form $A9EA$ is $6966$ but that has duplicate digits ($E=A$). So $R\notin\{9\}$.


 Therefore, $R=7$. $AREA$ is a multiple of $49$. The only multiples of $49$ that are of the form $A7EA$ are $3773$ which has duplicate digits and $4704$.


 Final answer: $P=9,I=6,R=7,A=4,E=0$ with $96\times7^2=4704$.

Solution for case 2:

 The same arguments show $R\notin\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.


 The other answers are:
$76\times8^2=4864$
$77\times7^2=3773$
$86\times9^2=6966$

